# Passing JSON values between JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am getting in JSON data, I am using dom to display the data, I want to embed a link to each search result displayed which when clicked passes that instance of data to another `<div>` block and display that result.

My HTML code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id:block 1 >
<div id:block 2>
<div id:block 3>
</body>
```

My JavaScript function is:

```
function addBooks(data) { // the data is a list of JSON objects


    var listdiv = document.createElement('li');
    listdiv.setAttribute('id', 'gBookListDiv');
    listdiv.innerHTML = ("Books Found:");
    parent.appendChild(listdiv);



    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


        //create each list item 
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        listItem.setAttribute('id', 'gBookListItem');
        parent.appendChild(listItem);
        link.setAttribute('href', '#');
        link.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayBook(data[i])');

        listItem.appendChild(link);
    }
}

function displayBook(bookData) {
    alert(bookData.title);
    if(document.getElementById("block2").style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById("block2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("block3").style.display = "block";
    }
    var headerTitle = document.getElementById('book-profile-title-header');
    headerTitle.innerHTML = bookData.title;

    var title = document.getElementById('book-profile-pic');
    headerTitle.innerHTML = bookData.title;

}
```

For some reason, I am not able to pass the instance of data to the `displayBook` function.

This is the error I get on Chrome

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: First of all you should fix the horribly wrong HTML code and then clean up your JavaScript code. For example, don't use `onclick` attributes if you can simply assign a function to the DOM element. Since you tagged the question with [tag:jquery] you might want to consider actually using it.

Comment: It is just a structure I am following , I am not using the HTML code as such

Comment: You should also post the actual codes you are using.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ --- you are probably passing JavaScript objects.

Comment: I don't see anywhere the `addBooks()` function is actually called. I see a function definition, but no calls.

Comment: Removed the jQuery tag since you're not using jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in this code:

```
link.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayBook(data[i])');
```

The handler runs in the global context so `data` is not defined there. Use a real function instead:

```
(function(i) {
    link.onclick = function() { displayBook(data[i]); }
})(i);
```

The self-executing function around it is necessary to create a separate `i` in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I am very new to javascript , I am not very sure on how to implement your answer code in mine !! I would be greatfull for any help

Comment: Simply replacing the first line with the second block of lines should do the job...